# copy line XX and paste it below my cursor (avy / ace jump style)

Tags: key-bindings, cut-copy-paste

I am wondering what the way of copying a line and pasting it below my cursor in vi/vim might be?

Current workflow (copy line 21 and paste it below cursor): `21ggyy''p`

Is there something shorter like: `21gyp`

I used emacs avy (https://github.com/abo-abo/avy) to do these kind of things before

Comment: Here you go: `:21t.`

Comment: also `21GY`CTRL-O`p`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I mean `21ggyy''p` is pretty fast, but here's a simple ex command:

```
:21t.
```

- Act on line 21
- t for copy ( `:copy` also works here)
- `.` Is special for the current line.
  (`:h :t`)

You can also supply relative ranges for both the location and destination e.g. `-5t+7` (copy the line 5 lines above the cursor to 7 below). Use `:m` instead of `:t` to move a line. Alternatively `:21y` to yank the line and paste with `p`

vim-easymotion seems to be similar to what avy is in emacs so you could also have a look at that.